# How to run Office Web Add in automatically on opening/closing Excel

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I am using 'Office Web Add In' to add some functionality into the office applications like excel,word etc.I want to trigger this functionality on opening/closing of excel.

Problem is the Office Web Add In runs only on user-interaction, when the user clicks on the menu in the ribbons option.

I am not able to trigger this add-in functionality automatically.
This is achievable in other type of add-ins such as Excel- VBA or VSTO Add In.

How can I trigger the add-in functionality automatically on opening excel ?

Have searched for a solution online, but could not find so.
Found something called as 'Auto Open Task Pane' feature which still does not works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are addin is built through office yeoman generator or may be on your own with proper manifest file.

Please see the official docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Please note: Auto open will only work on the below applications.

[image]

Also in your manifest file you can add

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
</Action>
```

More clear documentation is available on the official link.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ragavan,
However I do not want to open any task pane. Instead the logic should get executed in background on opening.closing of excel.
I think this kind of feature is not available yet.